# Extract nodes from XmlNodeList, with namespace, and where same child appears at multiple levels

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to extract those subnodes, but I had got just headache so far...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <supplyCrew xmlns="http://site.ddf.com">
     <login>
        <login>XXXX</login>
        <password>XXXX</password>
     </login>
     <flightInformation>
        <flights>
           <item>
              <arrivalDateTime>2010-11-08T22:48:00.000Z</arrivalDateTime>
              <arrivingCity>ORD</arrivingCity>
              <crewMembers>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>020040</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>Y</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>N</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>09000</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>N</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>Y</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
              </crewMembers>
           </item>
           <item>
              <arrivalDateTime>2010-11-08T20:29:00.000Z</arrivalDateTime>
              <arrivingCity>JFK</arrivingCity>
              <crewMembers>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>0538</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>Y</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>N</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
                 <item>
                    <employeeId>097790</employeeId>
                    <isDepositor>N</isDepositor>
                    <isTransmitter>Y</isTransmitter>
                 </item>
```

with the code I can get them, but I do not know how to select each one according to their tag name to insert them into a database.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:/Crew_Request_Sample.xml"); 
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");
foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

I need some direction, please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using `GetElementsByTagName("item")` here is that there are 2 levels of `item` node - one as a child of `flights` and another item as a child of `crewMembers`.

**Edit** Now that the full xml is pasted, it is clear that there is also a namespace involved as well. To handle namespaces, make use of a namespace manager to define aliases for the namespaces, which you can then use in the xpath queries:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace("s", "http://site.ddf.com");
var elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//s:crewMembers/s:item", nsm);
foreach (var node in elemList)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("s:employeeId", nsm).InnerText);
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("s:isDepositor", nsm).InnerText);
    Debug.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("s:isTransmitter", nsm).InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to include the tags <soapenv:Envelope and <soapenv:Body> in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//crewMembers/item"); ????

Comment: @BiancaFonseca No, you won't need to add any root elements (since the `//` will search past root nodes), but it may mean that your xml tree isn't in the global namespace, which means you will need an XmlNameSpaceManager.

Comment: @BiancaFonseca Thanks for the updated XML - you will need a namespacemanager as well. I've updated.

Comment: How I would get <item> <arrivalDateTime> and then crewMembers>            <item> or each crewMembers> <item> that belgons to <item><arrivalDateTime>?

Comment: Hi i have tried to follow this example for but i cant get it right,can you please help me

Comment: @ITForward this answer is obviously geared towards the OP's Xml structure and namespaces. Would suggest you ask a new question detailing exactly what it is that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using LINQ2XML..

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("C:/Crew_Request_Sample.xml"); 
XNamespace e = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace s = "http://site.ddf.com";
//this would access the nodes of item->crewMembers->item and put it into an Anonymous Type

var yourList=doc.Descendants(e+"Body")
.Descendants(s+"supplyCrew")
.Descendants(s+"flightInformation")
.Descendants(s+"flights")
.Descendants(s+"item")
.Descendants(s+"crewMembers")
.Descendants(s+"item")
.Select(
x=>new
{
//Anonymous Type
employeeId=x.Element(s+"employeeId").Value,
isDepositor=x.Element(s+"isDepositor").Value,
isTransmitter=x.Element(s+"isTransmitter").Value
}
);
```

You can then access yourList using for-each loop

```
foreach(var item in yourList)
{

Console.WriteLine(item.employeeId);
Console.WriteLine(item.isDepositor);
Console.WriteLine(item.isTransmitter);
}
```

Comment: I have also <soapenv:Envelope> and <soapenv:Body>. Do I have to include them before doc.Descendants("item").....?

Comment: @BiancaFonseca edit your question and show us the full format of `XML`..`soapenv` is a `namespace`.It should be added with the code.show the full XML structure so that I can help u wid that

Comment: @BiancaFonseca is this ur xml structure `Envelope->Body->item`

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll do it faster and easily using this technique

[Linq To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

There is a lot of examples in the site, so it 'll be easy to find what you want.
Hope it helps.